# Hello World Error Angular2

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, angular, angular2-routing

i recently did [this](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/) tutorial and i did the [Hero Editor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html) from Angular too. 
My Problem now is, everytime i go to "localhost:123/dashboard"  my Chrome browser just displays "Hello World" ("localhost:123" works fine). 
Same happens if i try to debug the scripts with Chrome.

Edit: I just uploaded my Code [here](https://github.com/Rian0702/AngularAdventure)

My Routing Code:

```
 @RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/heroes',
        name: 'Heroes',
        component: HeroesComponent
    }, {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    }, {
        path: '/detail/:id',
        name: 'HeroDetail',
        component: HeroDetailComponent
    }
]),
```

Files I referenced in my index.html:

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="libs/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/system.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/rx.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/http.dev.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                appScripts: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        System.import('appScripts/boot')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

my boot.ts:

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app'
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

the dashboard component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-dashboard',
    templateUrl: '/views/dashboard.component.html'
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    heroes: Hero[] = [];
    constructor(private _heroService: HeroService, private _router: Router) { }
    ngOnInit() {
          this._heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroes => this.heroes);
        //this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes);
    }
    gotoDetail(hero: Hero) {
        let link = ['HeroDetail', { id: hero.id }];
        this._router.navigate(link);
    }
}
```

Comment: show us `boot.ts` and  `dashboardComponent.ts`.

Comment: What do you have in the `/views/dashboard.component.html'` file? Thanks!

Comment: I just uploaded the Code to : https://github.com/Rian0702/AngularAdventure

Answer (score 1):

this resolved the issue for the routing:

```
 @Component({
selector: 'pv-app',
templateUrl: '/Views/PvStart.html',
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
providers: [
ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }), 
HTTP_PROVIDERS
],
pipes: [stringToDatePipe]
})


import {provide} from 'angular2/core'
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Hello World!" comes from Startup.cs in the configure function...

```
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
```

Commenting that out should eliminate that text being displayed.

Also, be sure that you set a base element as the first child of the head tag in index.html...

```
<head>
    <base href="/">

    <title>My Angular 2 App</title>
```

Lastly, try providing an absolute paths to HTML component counterpart...

```
@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "./app/app.component.html",
})
```

Reference: [Angular 2 Documentation: Developer Guide - Routing and Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)